# Display results where there ISN'T a match - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that displays records where there is a match between two tables:

```
select DISTINCT ug.name, ug.payroll_no, esr.assignment from user_group AS ug
inner join esrtraining AS esr on ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment, 2, 8)
```

How can I do the opposite? e.g. display the names from "User_Group" where there ISN'T a match? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an OUTER join instead of INNER, and then look for NULL in the WHERE clause on a column in the 2nd table that is not nullable:

```
select DISTINCT ug.name, ug.payroll_no, esr.assignment 
from user_group AS ug
left join esrtraining AS esr on ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment, 2, 8)
where esr.assignment is null
```

This is called an Exclusion Join.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a `NOT EXISTS` over the same criteria:

```
select DISTINCT ug.name, ug.payroll_no
from user_group AS ug
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    esrtraining AS esr 
    Where   ug.payroll_no = SUBSTRING(esr.assignment, 2, 8)
)
```

Comment: For what it is worth, while both solutions (at the time of commenting) will work, [`NOT EXISTS` performs better than `LEFT JOIN` in SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/), so this solution gets my vote. Or for more benchmarks - [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: @GarethD, do be very careful with performance generalizations.  `NOT EXISTS` performs better (much better, in fact) in the specific case that was tested in your linked report, sure.  But the OP's case is not strictly equivalent query-wise because of use of a function in the `WHERE` clause, and performance may anyway be strongly influenced by characteristics of the data that differ between the OP's case and the test case considered in the report you linked.  It is always best to *test* performance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I do appreciate your point, and agree that testing is always best, but in this case it isn't really a generalization it is a (fairly) well known flaw in the SQL Server optimiser that it cannot use an anti-semi join with a left join, so will still retrieve all matching records before doing the filter. The worst case scenario is that using `NOT EXISTS` will result in the same plan as `LEFT JOIN`. The function in the predicate only means that the relevant test case is the second on in Aaron Bertrand's article that I linked to where there is no usable index in the outer table.